# Why io_service can be used without run() for synchronous operations

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm interested why I can use boost::asio::io_service without run() call for syncronous socket operations? For example the following piece of code is valid :

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
tcp::acceptor a_event_data(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port + 2));
// Accept a connection to event socket
socket_ptr sock_event_data(new tcp::socket(io_service));
a_event_data.accept(*sock_event_data);

boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint_event_data = sock_event_data->remote_endpoint();
std::cout << "Accepted a connection for Event Data socket from " << endpoint_event_data.address().to_string() << std::endl;
```

But there is no call for run(). In case of asynchronous connections I must use it. Is it a dummy usage of io_service here just to interface with the system?

Comment: Fundamentally, yes; but, there is nothing preventing you from mixing async/sync operations, and the underlying framework doesn't really know which mode you will be using the framework in..

Comment: <sarcasm>It's like the buttons you have to push to cross the street. They don't really change the light, they just give you something to do while you wait. </sarcasm>

Answer (score 0):

The synchronous operation executes the I/O operations on the current thread. The asynchronous operation executes the I/O operations on one of the threads in `io_service`'s thread pool. If you don't call `run()` at least once (when there is actual work to do; otherwise it will immediately return) there is no thread in the pool.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronous operations on I/O objects implicitly run the io_service object for an individual operation.

The io_service functions run(), run_one(), poll() or poll_one() must be called for the io_service to perform asynchronous operations on behalf of a C++ program.

Notification that an asynchronous operation has completed is delivered by invocation of the associated handler. Handlers are invoked only by a thread that is currently calling any overload of run(), run_one(), poll() or poll_one() for the io_service.